Animation is stuttery on mobile phones [Solved]
I made a spinning wheel using chart.js pie chart and it works flawlessly on pc - basically am drawing a pie chart with datalabels for each option, and then spinning the chart accordingly. The problem comes when i try it on my mobile phone - the animation is very choppy.
"use client";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
Chart.register(...registerables, ChartDataLabels);

const WheelChartMobile = ({ segments, segColors, winningSegment, onFinished }) => {
  const wheel = useRef(null);
  const spinBtn = useRef(null);
  const [chart, setChart] = useState(null);

  const rotationValues = segments.map((_, index) => {
    return {
      minDegree: (index * 360) / segments.length,
      maxDegree: ((index + 1) * 360) / segments.length,
      value: segments[index],
    };
  });
  console.table(rotationValues);
  const data = new Array(rotationValues.length).fill(1);
  const pieColors = segColors;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!wheel.current) return;

    const ctx = wheel.current.getContext("2d");

    const chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
      plugins: [
        ChartDataLabels,
        {
          id: "customImageLabels",
          afterDraw: (chart) => {
            const {
              ctx,
              chartArea: { left, right, top, bottom, width, height },
            } = chart;
            const centerX = (left + right) / 2;
            const centerY = (top + bottom) / 2;
            const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

            chart.data.labels.forEach((label, index) => {
              const allowed = ["bones", "zrpy", "xrp"];
              if (!allowed.includes(label.split(" ")[1])) return;
              const angle =
                (chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index].startAngle +
                  chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index].endAngle) /
                2;
              const img = new Image();
              if (label.endsWith("bones")) {
                const imageX = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radius * 0.35;
                const imageY = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * radius * 0.35;
                img.src = "/images/wheel/bone.png";
                img.onload = () => {
                  ctx.drawImage(img, imageX - 10, imageY - 10, 20, 20);
                };
                ctx.drawImage(img, imageX - 10, imageY - 10, 20, 20); //image isnt drawn while wheel is spinning, thats why i draw the image a second time even after using onload
              } else if (label.endsWith("zrpy")) {
                const imageX = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radius * 0.37;
                const imageY = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * radius * 0.37;
                img.src = "/images/zerpaay.png";
                img.onload = () => {
                  ctx.drawImage(img, imageX - 11, imageY - 10, 23, 23);
                };
                ctx.drawImage(img, imageX - 11, imageY - 10, 23, 23);
              } else if (label.endsWith("xrp")) {
                img.src = "/images/xrp.png";
                const imageX = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radius * 0.38;
                const imageY = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * radius * 0.38;
                img.onload = () => {
                  ctx.drawImage(img, imageX - 15, imageY - 15, 30, 30);
                };
                ctx.drawImage(img, imageX - 15, imageY - 15, 30, 30);
              }
            });
          },
        },
        {
          id: "customCanvasBackgroundImage",
          afterDraw: (chart) => {
            const rimImage = new Image();
            rimImage.src = "/images/wheel/rim.png";
            const ctx = chart.ctx;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.drawImage(rimImage, -25, -30, 343, 343);
            rimImage.onload = () => {
              ctx.drawImage(rimImage, -25, -30, 343, 343);
            };
            ctx.restore();
          },
        },
      ],
      type: "pie",
      data: {
        labels: segments,
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: pieColors,
            data: data,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        animation: { duration: 0 },
        rotation: -90,
        plugins: {
          tooltip: false,
          legend: { display: false },
          datalabels: {
            color: "#ffffff",
            formatter: (value, context) => {
              if (
                context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex].endsWith("bones")
              ) {
                return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex].replace(
                  "bones",
                  "     "
                );
              } else if (
                context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex].endsWith(
                  "liscense"
                )
              ) {
                return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex].replace(
                  "liscense",
                  "liscense     "
                );
              } else if (
                context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex].endsWith("zrpy")
              ) {
                return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex].replace(
                  "zrpy",
                  "       "
                );
              } else if (
                context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex].endsWith("xrp")
              ) {
                return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex].replace(
                  "xrp",
                  "      "
                );
              } else {
                return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
              }
            },
            font: (context) => {
              const index = context.dataIndex;
              const width = context.chart.width + 10;
              const size = Math.round(width / 25);
              if (segments[index].endsWith("bones")) {
                return {
                  size: size + 10,
                  family: "Bowlby One SC",
                };
              } else if (segments[index].endsWith("zrpy")) {
                return {
                  size: size + 10,
                  family: "Bowlby One SC",
                };
              } else if (segments[index].endsWith("xrp")) {
                return {
                  size: size + 10,
                  family: "Bowlby One SC",
                };
              } else {
                return {
                  size: size,
                  family: "Bowlby One SC",
                };
              }
            },
            align: "center",
            rotation: (context) => {
              const wheelRotation = context.chart.options.rotation; // Get current rotation of the wheel
              const segmentIndex = context.dataIndex;
              const segmentAngle = 360 / segments.length;
              const rotation =
                wheelRotation + segmentIndex * segmentAngle + 110;
              return rotation;
            },
            // clip: true,
          },
        },
        borderColor: "#000",
      },
    });

    setChart(chartInstance);

    return () => {
      chartInstance.destroy();
      setChart(null);
    };
  }, [wheel]);

  let count = 0;
  let resultValue = 101;

  const spin = () => {
    spinBtn.current.disabled = true;
    wheel.current.classList.add("wheel-blur");
    let rotationInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (chart) {
        chart.options.rotation += resultValue;
        chart.update();
        let currentWinner = null;

        const angle = 180 / Math.PI + 2;
        chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.forEach((datapoint, index) => {
          const netStartAngle = (datapoint.startAngle * angle) % 360;
          const netEndAngle = (datapoint.endAngle * angle) % 360;
          if (280 > netStartAngle && 280 < netEndAngle) {
            currentWinner = chart.data.labels[index];
          }
        });

        if (chart.options.rotation >= 360) {
          count += 1;
          resultValue -= 5;
          chart.options.rotation = 0;
        }

        if (count >= 19 && currentWinner === winningSegment) {
          clearInterval(rotationInterval);
          count = 0;
          resultValue = 101;
          if (currentWinner) {
            onFinished(currentWinner);
          }
          wheel.current.classList.remove("wheel-blur");
        }

        //also spin the button with the wheel
        spinBtn.current.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(${chart.options.rotation}deg)`;

        chart.update();
      }
    }, 10);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //find the middle of chart and place the button there
    if (chart) {
      const {
        chartArea: { left, right, top, bottom, width, height },
      } = chart;
      const centerX = (left + right) / 2;
      const centerY = (top + bottom) / 2;
      spinBtn.current.style.left = `${centerX}px`;
      spinBtn.current.style.top = `${centerY}px`;
    }
  }, [chart]);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="container font-bowlbyUp">
        <canvas id="wheel" ref={wheel} className="mt-[10%]"/>
        <button id="spin-btn" ref={spinBtn} onClick={spin} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WheelChartMobile;

I tried using requestAnimationFrame to optimize it for mobile - but the problem persists, is there any better way to create a spinning wheel with dynamic options? I also tried reducing the setInterval delay from 10 to 20/30/40 ms - but it still doesnt work smoothly, maybe the excessive number of images is a problem?
update: i removed all the images (except the middle spinning button) and the wheel is now spinning smoothly! is there a way to show the images in a better way? Am using next.js and hosted on vercel

update: found a solution - preloaded the images and it works perfectly now!
